# Django ManyToMany filter

Tags: django, filter, many-to-many, countries

I have a Region infrastructure modeled as follows:  Each region has a ManyToMany of countries, and optionally states (if it's a region within the US)

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.models import USStateField
from django.db import models

from django_countries import CountryField


class CountryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, country):
        return self.get(country=country)


class Country(models.Model):
    country = CountryField(unique=True)

    objects = CountryManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('country',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.country.name)

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.country.code,)


class StateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, state):
        return self.get(state=state)


class State(models.Model):
    state = USStateField(unique=True)

    objects = StateManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('state',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.get_state_display()

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.state,)


class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    coordinator = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    is_us = models.BooleanField('Is a US region')
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    states = models.ManyToManyField(State, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Each user has a profile defined (partially) as follows:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user_profile')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    country = CountryField()
    state = USStateField(_(u'US only (determines user's region)'), blank=True, null=True)
```

I'm trying to filter a bunch of user objects by region.  So I have

```
        region = Region.objects.filter(id=self.request.GET['filter_region'])
        if len(region) == 0:
            raise Exception("Region not found for filter")
        if len(region) > 1:
            raise Exception("Multiple regions found for filter?")
        region = region[0]

        queryset = queryset.filter(user_profile__country__in=region.countries.all)
```

Sadly though, this returns an empty queryset.  I suspect it has to do with the fact that the "Country" model has a "country" field within it (terrible ambiguous naming, I know, not my code originally), and I'm only filtering by "Country" models, not the "country" fields within them.  (Does that make sense?)

How can I filter by a subfield of the ManyToMany field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why are you using `.filter()` if you want just a single item do:

```
region = Region.objects.get(id=self.request.GET['filter_region'])
```

That will raise an `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception if the object doesn't exist, but you're raising an exception if the queryset is empty anyways. If you need to catch that exception you can either use a `try...except` block or `get_object_or_404` if you're in a view.

Second, don't use `self.request.GET['filter_region']` directly. If the key isn't set you'll raise an `IndexError`. Use, instead:

```
self.request.GET.get('filter_region')
```

Now, as to your actual problem: `UserProfile.country` is a `CountryField` which is just a specialized `CharField`. Whereas `Region.countries` is a M2M with the model `Country`. The two are *not* comparable, which is why your queryset is coming back empty.

Make `UserProfile.country` a foreign key to `Country` and you're in business.